# UISearchBar not working when enter the first character?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I Would Implemented SearchBar Concept in my app but it have a bug, when i enter the first character in search bar it is not working and tableview not shows the related fields and it shows empty tableview but i enter the second character it displays the related fields in tableview, i don't know what mistake was made me please help me.

Here I give my code.

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
       NSLog(@"searching::");
       if(searchBar.text.length == 0)
       {
            [searchDict removeAllObjects];
            [arrayDict removeAllObjects];
            searchDict=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            arrayDict=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [self getJsonResponse];
            [self.tableView reloadData];    
       } else {
            [arrayDict removeAllObjects];
            arrayDict=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
       }
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self getSearchJsonResponse:searchBar.text];
       NSLog(@"searchDict::%@",searchDict);
       [self.tableView reloadData];
   });    
}
```

Comment: There is more information needed to properly answer the question, can you edit it adding the code of `getSearchJsonResponse`?

Comment: Agreed with @juanjo. We need more information to provide you with a better answer. It seems like you're sending out a web service call synchronously, which is not a best practice. We can help you fix that and your main issue if we have more information.

Comment: From the code you have posted, I am sure that it is perfectly fine.. problem must be in `getJsonResponse` or `getSearchJsonResponse` method

Comment: @saravana - your problem is resolved or not bro...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code from the chat, you need to thoroughly check your code for memory leaks and performance problems. It is littered all over the place.

That put aside, make the following changes to give your code a chance to work:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
  if(searchBar.text.length == 0) {
    [searchDict removeAllObjects];
    [arrayDict removeAllObjects];
    [self getJsonResponse];
    } 
  else {
    [arrayDict removeAllObjects];
    [self getSearchJsonResponse:searchBar.text];
    }
}
```

Also, wrap `[self.tableView reloadData]` in a dispatch to the main queue in your web services' completion blocks like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Additionally, what does `NSLog(@"SEARCHDICT::%@",searchDict);` log? Could it be possible that your lack of errorhandling is swallowing up a failed web service call response (like, empty search bar or 'I'm not searching for length 1')?

Comment: Not Working...@Jan Greve.

Comment: Could you provide the log result from the successful search with one char? I think the culprit might be your fail on the error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Take Two Arrays one searchResult & tabledataArr

In ViewDidLoad add this

```
self.searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[dataArr count]];
```

Add SearchBar Delegate

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope  
{

  [self.searchResult removeAllObjects];
  NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];

  self.searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [dataArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];

}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{

  [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

  return YES;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

  if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
  {
    return [self.searchResult count];
  }
 else
 {
    return [dataArr count];
 }
}
```

In CellForRowAtIndex also add this in else part

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: I will Try this but not works properly...@Uma Madhavi.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your tableView is reloaded before the json call is done.
Try with completionBlock:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
NSLog(@"searching::");
if(searchBar.text.length == 0)
{
    [searchDict removeAllObjects];
    [arrayDict removeAllObjects];

    //Reload when networkcall is complete
   [self getJsonResponseWithCompletionBlock:^(NSMutableArray *allResults, NSError *error) {
        //if no error fill Dictionary and reload ...

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
} else {
   ...
```

And for json call like this

```
-(void)getJsonResponseWithCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSMutableArray *allResults, NSError *error))completionBlock {

//Do what ever is needed to get data
//...

//when data is ready call block
completionBlock(allResults,nil);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text` method to get the text entered in `UISearchBar`. Method looks like

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

NSString * txt = [searchBar.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];    
return YES;
```

}

Here 'txt' is the text which appears in the `UISearchBar`. Now you do filter results by using 'txt' string. Call `reload` on `UISearchBarController` tableview to update search results.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'searchText' value that gets passed in rather than trying to pull the value out of the UI component. 'searchText' should always have the correct value. 'searchBar.text' may not have been updated yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
if ([searchText isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [searchDict removeAllObjects];
        [arrayDict removeAllObjects];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.searchResultController.tableView reloadData];
    });
}
[YourController cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(applySearch) object:nil];
if (![searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(applySearch) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

with ApplySearch:

```
- (void)applySearch{
    [self getSearchJsonResponse:searchBar.text];
}
```

I think in `getSearchJsonResponse:` it should be:

```
- (void)getSearchJsonResponse:(NSString *)text {
     //Maybe like this:
     [self getJsonResponseWithCompletionBlock:^(NSMutableArray *allResults, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }];
}
```

Maybe function set request of you can be different.

Answer (score 0):

instead of checking text on search bar, you must use searchText.

I am doing the same thing and this solved my problem. Hope it helps you too.

Answer (score -1):

When text is editing in search bar textfield, then this delegate is getting called.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *text = [[textField text] stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    // make search call with updated text.
    [self startSeachWithText:text];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This method will not work for UISearchBar, this wil work for UITextField.